# Why canvas is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Here i am creating the canvas element using javascript as given below

```
canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.id = "canvas";
canvas.height = "450";
canvas.width = "745";
canvas.style="background- color:#ffffff";
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
console.log(canvas);
jq("#container").append (canvas);
```

Here canvas shows undefined and when i create as given below

```
canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.id = "canvas";
canvas.height = "450";
canvas.width = "745";
canvas.style="background- color:#ffffff";
console.log(canvas);
jq("#container").append (canvas);
```

Here it works fine. why the above one does not work?

Comment: In the first case you are doing `document.getElementById` before you've added it to the DOM. So of course it's undefined. Although, I don't know why you are trying to get a reference to it with `getElementById` when you already have a reference to it. Or why you are mixing jquery in with plain javascript DOM methods.

Comment: Before appending it to the document, `document.getElementById` will not find the node.

Answer (score 5):

The first version expects canvas to have been rendered to the DOM with the check to `document.getElementById()`. However, the element has never been rendered to the DOM although it is fully formed. The result from `canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");` is that it is overwritten with `null`, and then that is what you attempt to send to jquery.

In the second example, the element is passed as an argument to jquery's append method, which then appends the element to an already existing element on the page "#container"

In other words, the difference is that version 1 uses this:

```
jq("#container").append (null);
```

and version 2 uses this:

```
jq("#container").append (canvas);
```

Comment: Technically, `getElementById` returns `null` not `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi - Thanks, I will make the clarification :)

Answer (score 4):

`document.getElementById()` will only find elements that are attached to the `document` tree.

In the 1st example, the `<canvas>` remains a detached node in memory, until it's discarded by the assignment:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); // null
// replaces the reference to the `<canvas>`, allowing garbage collection
```

It would have to be appended first to be found:

```
// ...

jq("#container").append(canvas);

canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
console.log(canvas);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7bh40b0b/